# When login into terminal, display custom text

Tags: ubuntu, login, motd

When I loggin to my linux system through PuTTY, I'm getting this below text.Welcome to

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Jan 27 08:58:36 IST 2015

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           109
  Usage of /:   2.3% of 71.00GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 9%                IP address for eth0: 192.168.5.135
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

55 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***
Last login: Tue Jan 27 08:58:40 2015 from 192.168.5.102
```

It is showing OS name, system load, memory info, no. of updates, uptime etc.. I also want to display few more things like below.

```
Bluetooth is ON. Address: 00:AA:08:34:54
USB is conneted. Mount point '/mnt/mydrive/'
Mysql service is running
```

I know that we can write these scripts in `~/.bashrc` to show above info. But I don't like to add there. And also I want show my custom text above `*** System restart required ***` line. So I want know how system printing this information. Thanks.

Comment: please paste your /etc/motd here ?

Comment: There is no such file. @soubunmei

Comment: then it must be /run/motd.dynamic .

Comment: i believe the `System information as of Tue Jan 27 08:58:36 IST 2015` line is not *dynamic* content , but is generated by the update-motd script .

Comment: Yes, `/run/motd.dynamic` file exists. And every thing is static @soubunmei

Comment: it finds out that forementioned script belongs to package update-notifier-common .

Comment: so , if you want some real-time message , put in the /etc/profile or ~/.profile or /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc .

Comment: otherwise if you want to customize existing motd , you can play with some templates and hooks . refer to documentation **and the sourcecode** of /usr/sbin/update-motd .

Comment: But I dont have any `update-motd` file. And thanks for info

Comment: and maybe you can find out some way to make update-motd happen more frequently , maybe by means of a cronjob . thus you can make the message somewhat semi-dynamic . ( does a one minute interval sound fine ? )

Comment: you don't find update-motd ? let me see , manual says there should be a  /etc/update-motd.d/ directory , check that out ?

Comment: Yes I have `/etc/update-motd.d/` and I can see few files "00-header  10-help-text  50-landscape-sysinfo  90-updates-available  91-release-upgrade  98-fsck-at-reboot  98-reboot-required"

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's motd is generated by running the files in `/etc/update-motd.d/`.

On my 14.04 system, the `*** System restart required ***` message appears to be generated by the script `98-reboot-required`, so to add your custom messages, you should create a script with a number less than 98, and have it run commands or echo whatever messages you want. Don't forget to make your new script executable.

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/